# How to remove index from pandas DataFrame.str.contains return

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I am trying to find a substring within a pandas dataframe. I can find the substring with the method str.contains(), but that returns the row number index where the substring was found. I do not want that row number index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': [Jordan, Pippen, Rodman], 'Number': [23, 33, 91]})
data = df[df['Name'].str.contains('Pip', case=False, regex=False)]
print(data)
```

Actual Output:

```
     Name     Number
1    Pippen     33
```

Expected Output:

```
Name     Number
Pippen     33
```

I have tried the following to no avail:

```
data.style.hide(axis='index')
data.style.hide_index()
data = data.reset_index(drop=True)
```

For further clarification, see [this](https://datascienceparichay.com/article/pandas-search-for-string-in-dataframe-column/) page to see the how the row index is part of the output. I just want that row index to be removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
print(data)
```

with

```
print(data.to_string(index=False))
```

which yields

[image]

Comment: I want to be able to access the dataframe contents later, so converting to a string won't work for me because I then lose easy access to the data.

Comment: The dataframe `data` remains unchanged as `.to_string()` is not an in-place operation and therefore `data` remains accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you cannot have a dataframe without an index. Even for an empty dataframe the index is Index([]) just an empty index but its there.

Not sure why would you want to do this. But you can set the index to empty strings as indices if that's what you want.

```
data.set_index(pd.Index(['']*len(data)), inplace=True)
```

print(data):

```
    Name  Number
  Pippen      33
```

Comment: This helped a lot, thanks! Essentially, I was trying to get the row data from some dataframe that contains a certain substring. I did that with
```
df.str.contains(substring, case=False, regex=False)
```
but the problem was that the return was a boolean list with row numbers. When I tried to get the row data which contained the substring, it was also spitting out the row index, which was messing up formatting because I was trying to add that to a separate dataframe.